# interface for multiple fields of the same type

Tags: typescript

I have multiple transactions which I explicitly do not want to put them in an array. Instead I want to have them as fields. Like this:

```
{
    ['fixtureId']: {
        transactionId: string;
        donation: boolean;
    },
    ['fixtureId']: {
        transactionId: string;
        donation: boolean;
    }
}
```

How does the interface looks like?

Comment: Does the string `'fixtureId'` change? I mean, it would have to in order for them to be properties on the same object...

Comment: Yes, fixtureId is always different.

Comment: [`interface SomeType { transactionId: string; donation: boolean; } interface Whatever { [fixtureId: string]: SomeType; }`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAqBPABxQG9kwo4QBnRMYdEASQBMAuZK80AcwG5lmDOHQbsARunQAbCJX4BfAFChIsRCgDqAC2EQAbtGSkA2jGAAPMAFcoEFu05QeAXXYZs+IgsWKEDTsgA7jqQeuzaugZQyAC8RorIichwYggAjABMAMzsxAlJBeSUNAgiTGzIAOSZWZUANPkFiYIgwvQg7ORWEI3I8g0FzBAwACwArABsub2FFNS07fZV4xP1M0ktbaLI8FJUPQVK8rxAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
export interface IFixtures {
  [fixtureId: string]: {
    transactionId: string;
    donation: boolean;
  }
}
```

More info e.g. here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/indexable-types.html